# ¿Como puedo replicar la función CALCULATE de DAX en tableau?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo la siguiente función:
Registro eliminados = CALCULATE(COUNT(registros),registros="ELIMINADOS")
necesito replicarlas en tableau.